# Usage of createBond() with Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating an app that communicates through Bluetooth Low Energy with a device, mostly to have the phone display the data from the device. I need to implement functionality where if the device and phone are moved into range, they will automatically identify as a pair and will connect without user interaction. I have been looking into Bonding to accomplish this.

I am currently trying to take the currently connected device and create a bond with it when the user clicks a `ListItem`. I call `BluetoothDevice.createBond()` on a reference to the connected `BluetoothDevice` variable. The Android Developer [site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond()) says that for `BluetoothDevice.createBond()`, false will be returned if there is an error, and that I should register for ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED to be informed when Bonding has started and is completed.

I have a few problems with `createBond()`, which is where my questions lie:

1. Most of the time `createBond()` returns false, indicating that it has failed to start bonding. What are some possible reasons for this? (My phone runs Android 4.4.2, API19 which is where `createBond()` is introduced - so it isn't that.)
2. Sometimes, bonding apparently succeeds because the code inside the ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED receiver will be called. I may misunderstand what is involved in maintaining and using a bond, but the BLE device does not automatically connect to the phone when it is in range, so I am probably missing some code. After establishing a bond, what else do I need to do?
3. In the event that `createBond()` is no good for whatever reason (e.g. I have to make the app work for API18 when `createBond()` is introduced in API19), what alternatives are there?

Examples would be incredibly helpful. Finding information about bonding with BLE has been frustrating. Self-teaching this stuff has been difficult, especially with no tutorials lying around. On top of that, some people say it's impossible due to being "Just Works" when others say it's certainly possible. BLE is still a big cloud of confusion for me, so for now, some clarity with `createBond()` would be much appreciated.